# ConverterNotFoundException after upgrading Spring to 4.3.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

We're in the middle of upgrading our libraries and we upgraded Spring from `4.2.4` to `4.3.4` and Spring data from `1.9.2` to `1.10.5`. We're also using Hibernate `5.2.5.Final` to talk to a MySql DB.

After doing so we get the following error on a Spring conversion.

`org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.javatuples.Pair<?, ?>] to type [my.namespace.Category]`

And it's for this repo call.

`@Query("select new org.javatuples.Pair(cpc.category, count(*)) from UnlinkedProductCategorization cpc where cpc.myField = ?1 group by cpc.category")
    Collection<Pair<Category,Long>> countByCategoryForContainer(MyFieldType selfContainer);`

Nothing in this repo has changed, and if we revert back to everything works. We have other cases where we use `select new org.javatuples.Pair(someEntityHere, count(*))` that still work, so I can't figure out why the upgrade would have broken it. And why it thinks it should try to convert the Pair to a Category, which really doesn't make sense.

Here's the call stack just after our last method

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.javatuples.Pair<?, ?>] to type [com.siftit.domain.core.category.Category]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:324)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:206)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:187)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ProjectingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter$1.convert(ResultProcessor.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.countByCategoryForContainer(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer directly, but here are some things you should look into/try, that are to long for a comment:

1. You say you have other methods using `new Pair`. How does the signature of those look like?
2. Set a break point where the exception occurs and check what it is doing/trying to do. Look out for:

   a) Maybe there are multiple instances of the Pair class or the Category class loaded via different classloaders.

   b) Maybe the types of what you get from the database changed, like now getting `BigInts`, instead of `Long`
3. Isolate the problem: copy your project, remove everything not related to the problem until you get something so small that it can be reasonably copied into a SO question. Often a long the way you'll find the issue, if not we are here to help.